# Segmentation fault with scanf and strings in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am a beginner with c, and I am having a problem with scanf and strings.

here is an example I wrote of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* string;
    scanf("%s", &string);
    if (strcmp(string, "Foo") == 0)  //segmentation fault here
        printf("Bar");
}
```

basically, this code compiles, but when I run it I get a segmentation fault in strcmp()

if I replace the "string" in that line with "&string" it works, but I get this error from the compiler

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: note: expected 'const char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

which makes me think that this solution is not really ideal.

also If I declare string like this:

```
char string[100];
```

that works without any warnings, but that is also not ideal because I am not sure how large the string is going to be.

Is there a better solution I'm missing here, or are these my only options?

thank you.

Comment: Read a book - C isn't a language to learn by trial and error. (In many cases if you get something wrong your program will silently appear to work , or give confusing results; and as a result you end up with incorrect mental models and an eternal lack of understanding of the difference between arrays and pointers, etc.)

Comment: You need to declare string large enough (as you surmised), but how big? Read about malloc.  Had you declared the string as, char string[1]; you might have had a program that worked, sometimes, but failed because the location where you were storing the sscanf()'ed string was too small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* string;
scanf("%s", &string);
```

`string` is not pointing to any valid memory location. Allocate memory using `malloc` to an array of characters and copy input to it. Make sure allocated memory has space for null termination character. Remember to `free` the memory to avoid leaks.

Comment: Or just make an array of `char` on the stack and avoid `malloc`.

Comment: Ok, that works. Is there a way that I can allocate the memory based on the size of the string the user inputs? that way I don't have to guess how big the string is going to be

Answer (score 1):

Just try that code

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     int main(void)
     {
       char* string;
       string=(char *)malloc(3); /*allocate the memory to string cahr pointer(default pointer point to single byte and if you print pointer variable don't used & character)*/                                                      
       scanf("%s", string);
       if (strcmp(string, "Foo") == 0)  
            printf("Bar\n");
     }
```

Comment: 3 is not a reasonable size for a `malloc`-ed string buffer. It should be at least 4.

Answer (score 0):

While declaring a char *. it will not having any memory location. so you have to allocate a
memory location before you use that variable.
     char *p;
     p=malloc(sieof(char) * size of string);

then you use scanf() function. it will work properly.

when we are accessing a unknown memory(ie unallocated memory). then it will through the segmentation fault